# error in installing my_sql on AWS EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-emr, mysql-connector

I'm trying to start up MYSQL on my EMR cluster but it's showing as ERROR 1045 (2800): Access denied as shown in picture posted . Wat should i do ?[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49a4f.png)

After executing these commands :

wget https://de-mysql-connector.s3.amazonaws.com/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.tar.gz
tar -xvf mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.tar.gz
cd mysql-connector-java-8.0.25/
sudo cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/

I tried setting password of database but it wasn't connecting to it .

Answer (score 0):

it took my 3 days for getting how to install mysql on EMR

Install MySQL using the following command:
**sudo yum install mysql-server -y**

Start the MySQL service using the following command:
**sudo service mysqld start**

Set a root password for MySQL using the following command:
**sudo mysqladmin -u root password yourpassword**

Optionally, you can secure your MySQL installation by running the secure installation script using the following command:
**sudo mysql_secure_installation**

This script will prompt you to set the root password, remove anonymous users, disallow root login remotely, remove the test database, and reload the privilege tables.